# Why explicitly specified read only field is also writable in django serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_info = CategorySerializer(source="category", read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = ('id','title','description','category',) + ('category_info',)
        extra_kwargs = {'category': {'write_only': True},}
```

The category_info field is still writable.
I tried write_only=False and required=False also but nothing works.
Can someone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you share an example of your request data? And can you show the whole serializer

Comment: I have shown the complete serializer. please check.

Comment: You defined `extra_kwargs = {'category': {'write_only': True},}`. This will make category writable. Is that not what you expect?

Comment: I tried by removing it but not solved. Thanks for your help.